# Why do we need to add a reference to an assembly, from which a class library project inherits, into a consumer project?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

My solution consists of two projects:

- a class library project (named as `DataAccess`) that defines a class (named as `MyContext`) inheriting from `DbContext`. As `DbContext` is defined in `EntityFramework.dll` assembly, I need to add a reference to this assembly into this class library project. I have no confusion in this mechanism.
- a console application project (named as `Tester`) that consumes the `DataAccess` class defined in the class library above. Adding a reference to the assembly of the class library above is understandable. Unfortunately, I cannot compile the solution until I add a reference to `EntityFramework.dll` into this console application.

Why do we need to add a reference to an assembly, from which a class library project inherits, into a consumer project?
In my mental model, it is enough to only add a reference to `DataAccess` project assembly into `Tester` project and the chained references should be done automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a lot of the behaviour in `MyContext` is inherited from the base class in entity framework. If you call those methods (e.g. `SaveChanges()`) from `Tester`, the `Tester` app needs a reference to the class library where the method is defined.

If you would only access methods of `MyContext` that are defined in your class library, I think you could do without the reference to the base class.

Comment: But if I use database first and add EDMX from database, the console application is not need entityframework.dll . But code firstt needs it.

Answer (score 4):

Because otherwise `EntityFramework.dll` wont get copied to the output directory when you build your project and your library won't be able to access it.

If you are able to embed `EntityFramework.dll` into your library (right click the reference -> Properties) then you won't need to reference it on your console application.